# How can I check line contains inline sql statement using Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on code check functionality which is almost completed using javascript. I want to check php code files if they contains inline sql statements. How this can be possible with using javascript.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty strange use-case too, so I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Might want to add detail to your question.

Comment: You want to inspect PHP file using JavaScript? Huh?

Comment: I am working on code check functionality (Most of part we did like inline css style check using indexOf, line char count using lenght). I want to check if code contains sql statement in it.

Comment: I have tried with using indexOf for SELECT, FROM, UPDATE, INSERT  statements but this is not solutions for this. It gives me wrong results as file contains these words as html or in echo. Also sql statements may have multiple lines.

Comment: Are you trying to protect yourself against SQL injection attacks? If so, this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: @Abhijeet I updated the answer again. Check the results :)

Comment: yeah. if you want to check for inline sql that's an awful way to do it

Answer (score -1):

Try these expressions below

```
 // 1st expression (simplest)
^(SELECT|INSERT\sINTO\s|DELETE|UPDATE).+;?$/gi

//2nd expression (a better one)
^(?=(SELECT|INSERT|DELETE|UPDATE)+).*(?=(FROM|SET|INTO)+).*(WHERE|ORDER\sBy|LIMIT)?;?$

//3rd expression (even better)
(?=(SELECT|INSERT|DELETE|UPDATE)+).*(?=(FROM|SET|INTO)+).*(WHERE|ORDER\sBy|LIMIT)?;?
```

---

```
// Strings tested so far using third expression (no fails so far)

SELECT password FROM users WHERE 1
I'd like to select all my best books
WHERE are you?
UPDATE users SET password = "hacked"
We were in group of three
SELECT all elements of something
I'm FROM / from someland
DELETE * FROM users WHERE
I do love regex
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1;
SELECT password FROM users WHERE 1 LIMIT 1
Insert a freaking coin into machine
INSERT INTO users VALUES
DELETE * FROM users;
DELETE password FROM users LIKE 'admin'
UPDATE users SET password = '' 
OMG!
SELECT Chuck Norris for a president
UPDATE Brian SET tolerance = 'higher'    <--- though, a proper SQL ;)
SELECT * FROM users
Let's check this SELECT user FROM users; whatever
SELECT user FROM users
SELECT user, password FROM users
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE 'admin'
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = 'admin'
SELECT user FROM users WHERE password = '' ORDER BY user;
DELETE * FROM users
DELETE FROM users
DELETE FROM users WHERE user = "admin";
UPDATE users SET password = '';
UPDATE users SET username = 'hohoho' AND password = '';
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('santa', 'hohoho');
INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('santa', 'hohoho');
```

Usage:

```
pattern = /(?=(SELECT|INSERT|DELETE|UPDATE)+).*(?=(FROM|SET|INTO)+).*(WHERE|ORDER\sBy|LIMIT)?;?/gi;
pattern.test('SELECT user, password FROM users'); // true
```

Testing in progress... :) [Regex Fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/xX5oG8/5)

Comment: How is that regex giving the results you indicate? You have used square brackets incorrectly. They should be parens. Square brackets are to enclose a character class - all possible values for ONE character.

Comment: Setting aside my other misgivings about this approach, you clearly must mean `(` and `)` where you have `[` and `]`.

Comment: Please, a little patience, I see the holes :)

Comment: hey @hex494D49 thanks! your solution going to work. I am checking for this solutions and it's working on many of my files.

Comment: @Abhijeet Cool! It's challenging :) I'm improving it and testing on some more complicated strings

Comment: I don't think you understand regex character classes (square brackets). Your current expression `^[SELECT|INSERT\sINTO|DELETE|UPDATE]+[a-zA-Z0-9|\s*\s]+[FROM].+$`, while matching all of the intended input strings, also has many false positives because you specify that the FIRST CHARACTER must be one of these: `S,E,L,C,T,|,I,N ...`. Here's one of the ridiculous matches for a SQL statement using your regex: `OMG!`. Try it!

Comment: Sorry, that `OMG!` in my last comment needs a space at the beginning; then it matches: " OMG!" Either way, not quite valid SQL.

Comment: @BrianStephens A nice and constructive comment would be just enough :) So, cheer up, life is beautiful!